# Piecewise function of random variable

Tags: probability

I have the following problem, which I do have my own solution for, I am however quite unsure whether they are correct and looking for someone who is able verify or correct them.

The length, X, of a file is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda = 2$, i.e.,

$f_{X}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
2e^{-2x}, for\space x \geq 0\\ 
0, otherwise
\end{matrix}\right.$

The costs, $Y_{1}$, for transmitting the file over communication channel 1 are equal to $5+10X$. The costs, $Y_{2}$, for transmitting the file over communication channel 2 are given by

$Y_{2}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
5, for\space X \leq 0.5\\ 
15, otherwise
\end{matrix}\right.$

a. Give the cumulative distribution functions of the random variables $X, Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$

*My solution:*

$F_{X}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1-e^{-2x}, for\space x \geq 0\\ 
0, otherwise
\end{matrix}\right.$

$F_{Y_{1}}(y_{1})=P[Y_{1}\leq y_{1}]=P[5+10X\leq y_{1}]=P[x\leq \frac{y_{1}-5}{10}]=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1-e^{\frac{5-y_{1}}{5}}, for\space x \geq 0\\ 
0, otherwise
\end{matrix}\right.$

*This is the one I am having troubles with:*

$F_{Y_{2}}(y_{2})\left\{\begin{matrix}
1-e^{-10}, for\space 0 \leq x \leq 0.5\\
1-e^{-30}, for\space x \geq 0.5\\
0, otherwise
\end{matrix}\right.$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_{Y_{2}}$ is wrong. $Y_2$ take sonly the vaues $5$ and $15$. The correct values are  $F_{Y_{2}}(y)=0$ if $y <5$, $P\{X\leq 0.5\}=1-\frac 1 e$ if  $5 \leq y <15$ and $1$ if $y \geq 15$.